# Biblatex field venue+eventdate without round brackets

Tags: biblatex, macros, brackets

I am looking for a solution to remove the round brackets in the reference list for the type `@inproceedings`. The original version is like:
[image]

As you can see, the `venue+eventdate` has round brackets around it:

> (Shanghai, China, 2011 May 09)

Any idea how to remove the brackets to get the following?

> Shanghai, China, 2011 May 09

Attached a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{eventdate}{%
  \thefield{eventyear}%
  \space
  \mkbibmonth{\thefield{eventmonth}}%
  \space%
  \thefield{eventday}}

\begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
@inproceedings{Baker2011,
 author = {Baker, Christopher R. and Dolan, John M. and Wang, Shige and Litkouhi, Bakhtiar B.},
 bookpagination = {page},
 booktitle = {2011 IEEE Int. Conf. Robotics and Automation},
 doi = {10.1109/ICRA.2011.5980355},
 eventdate = {2011-05-09/2011-05-13},
 eventtitle = {2011 IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation (ICRA 2011)},
 isbn = {978-1-61284-386-5},
 keywords = {software architecture},
 pages = {6071--6077},
 publisher = {IEEE},
 location = {Piscataway, NJ},
 title = {Toward adaptation and reuse of advanced robotic software},
 venue = {Shanghai, China},
 year = {2011}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{database}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry: I meant for the type @inproceedings

Comment: The definition of the `eventdate` field format is not the usual way to redefine date formats. Normally that happens via date macros. Since you want to switch from `mm dd yyyy` format to `yyyy mm dd` format, a bit more code is involved, but you can already see that your code swallows the end date: https://gist.github.com/moewew/d8e7e51eb53f10fea6bfcc18fb79aa6f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parenthesis are added by the `event+venue+date` macro. You can change its definition to remove them and add the full stop requested in comments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{%
  \printfield{eventtitle}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{eventtitleaddon}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{venue}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printeventdate
  \newunit}

\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
     \iffieldbibstring{#1}
       {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
       {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}%
       \mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#3}
         {}
         {\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}}%
  }%
%
  \protected\gdef\lbx@us@mkdaterangetrunc@long#1#2{%
    \begingroup
      \blx@metadateinfo{#2}%
      \iffieldundef{#2year}
        {}
        {\printtext[#2date]{%
           \datecircaprint
           \iffieldundef{#2season}
             {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2year}{#2month}{#2day}%
              \blx@printtime{#2}{}}%
             {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2year}{#2season}}%
           \dateeraprint{#2year}%
           \dateuncertainprint
           \iffieldundef{#2endyear}
             {}
             {\iffieldequalstr{#2endyear}{}
                {\mbox{\bibdaterangesep}}
                {\bibdaterangesep
                 \enddatecircaprint
                 \iffieldundef{#2season}
                   {\iffieldsequal{#2year}{#2endyear}
                     {\iffieldsequal{#2month}{#2endmonth}
                        {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{}{#2endday}}
                        {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}}
                     {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}%
                    \blx@printtime{#2}{end}}
                   {\iffieldsequal{#2year}{#2endyear}
                      {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{}{#2endseason}}
                      {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endseason}}}%
                 \enddateuncertainprint
                 \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}}}}%
    \endgroup}%
%
  \protected\gdef\lbx@us@mkdaterangetruncextra@long#1#2{%
    \begingroup
      \blx@metadateinfo{#2}%
      \iffieldundef{#2year}
        {}
        {\printtext[#2date]{%
           \datecircaprint
           \iffieldundef{#2season}
             {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2year}{#2month}{#2day}%
              \blx@printtime{#2}{}}%
             {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2year}{#2season}}%
           \dateeraprint{#2year}%
           \dateuncertainprint
           \iffieldundef{#2endyear}
             {\printfield{extradate}}
             {\iffieldequalstr{#2endyear}{}
                {\printfield{extradate}%
                 \mbox{\bibdaterangesep}}
                {\bibdaterangesep
                 \enddatecircaprint
                 \iffieldundef{#2season}
                   {\iffieldsequal{#2year}{#2endyear}
                     {\iffieldsequal{#2month}{#2endmonth}
                        {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{}{#2endday}}
                        {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}}
                     {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}%
                    \blx@printtime{#2}{end}}
                   {\iffieldsequal{#2year}{#2endyear}
                      {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{}{#2endseason}}
                      {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endseason}}}%
                 \printfield{extradate}%
                 \enddateuncertainprint
                 \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}}}}%
    \endgroup}%
%
}
\makeatletter


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
@inproceedings{Baker2011,
  author         = {Baker, Christopher R. and Dolan, John M. and Wang, Shige and Litkouhi, Bakhtiar B.},
  bookpagination = {page},
  booktitle      = {2011 IEEE Int. Conf. Robotics and Automation},
  doi            = {10.1109/ICRA.2011.5980355},
  eventdate      = {2011-05-09/2011-05-13},
  eventtitle     = {2011 IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation (ICRA 2011)},
  isbn           = {978-1-61284-386-5},
  keywords       = {software architecture},
  pages          = {6071--6077},
  publisher      = {IEEE},
  location       = {Piscataway, NJ},
  title          = {Toward adaptation and reuse of advanced robotic software},
  venue          = {Shanghai, China},
  year           = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{database.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{Baker2011}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Christopher R. Baker et al. “Toward adaptation and reuse of advanced robotic software”. In: 2011 IEEE Int. Conf. Robotics and Automation. 2011 IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation (ICRA 2011). Shanghai, China, 2011 May 9–13. Piscataway, NJ: IEEE, 2011, pp. 6071–6077. ISBN: 978-1-61284-386-5. DOI: 10.1109/ICRA.2011.5980355.]

Note that the date format was changed using the appropriate language-specific commands and not via the field format. Since the format was changed from the American `mm dd yyyy` to ISO `yyyy mm dd` two helper macros had to be adjusted, which means that the code may look a bit overwhelming at first glance. Note how the end date is not suppressed any more.

Comment: Thank you, @samcarter. Very fast response :-) Do you have a hint how I can add a dot between the booktitle and the `event+venue+date` block? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: @HB4711 I do get a period after the booktitle. Maybe you mean after the eventtitle?

Comment: You are totally right. I meant the eventtitle.

Comment: @HB4711 Please see my updated code.

Comment: The `\ifboolexpr` in `event+venue+date` is superfluous now, so that we can simply say `\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{%
  \printfield{eventtitle}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{eventtitleaddon}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{venue}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printeventdate%
  \newunit}`

Comment: Same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446732/biblatex-field-venueeventdate-without-round-brackets#comment1122250_446732: I suggest to change the date format the proper way and not via the field format: I know it is almost 90 lines longer, but it uses the proper interfaces: https://gist.github.com/moewew/d8e7e51eb53f10fea6bfcc18fb79aa6f

Comment: @moewe Would you like to post an answer of your own? I'll happily delete mine.

Comment: Nah, but I could edit your answer if you are OK with that.

Comment: @moewe Sure, please go ahead.

Comment: Thanks, I edited you answer. Hope you don't mind it got a lot longer ...